# separation of reference and footnote numbers by a comma

Tags: footnotes, citing, revtex

I'm using `revtex4-1` as documentclass and would like to place a footnote after a citation,

```
\cite{...}\footnote{}
```

However, the consecutive superscript numbers in the resulting pdf are not separated by a comma. How to solve this issue without having to place a `$^,$` in between?

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[prb,showpacs,superscriptaddress,groupedaddress,twocolumn]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[verbose,hypertexnames=false,bookmarksopenlevel=1,filecolor=blue,
linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,pdfstartview=FitH,bookmarksopen,bookmarksnumbered,
colorlinks,plainpages=false,linktocpage]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\title{test}
Hello world\cite{test}\footnote{hello}

\begin{thebibliography}{6}
\bibitem{test} James D. Murray, William vanRyper: {\sl Graphics File
    Formats}. O'Reilly\&Associates, Inc., Sebastopol, CA, 1994.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Would `\cite{...}\textsuperscript{,}\footnote{...}` work for you?

Comment: @Mico: looks good!